# Refinable String managed property uneditable

Tags: managed-property, sharepoint-list-filter, search-schema

I have just purchased microsoft365 for business (becoming a freelance), and I want to set new managed properties for a list I've created.
when trying to edit new refinableString properties, most of the fields are uneditable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbk9f.png)

can't find what's blocking me.
Would appreciate help to pass this hurdle,
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Online, you can't create new managed properties. They are either created automatically, in case of Managed Metadata fields, or you have to re-use existing managed properties. You can change only a couple of settings in the existing RefinableStringXX, RefinableDateXX,etc managed properties. You can only change **Alias** and the **Mapping to crawled properties**
[image]

[image]

Typically, that should be more than enough to setup your search schema. Don't worry if the rest of the properties are greyed out - it's totally fine. Just provide a user-friendly alias and setup a mapping to one of the crawled properties. This should make it possible to search your custom metadata using an alias.

Comment: Thanks!I understand that the Crawled properties are created automatically too, so no problem here too?

Comment: Correct! Crawled properties are created automatically after you add some content with field values filled. Might take an hour or so.

Comment: Awsome! 
Thank you :)